# Can I decrypt given CTR ciphertext with ECB, knowing the nonce and the AES key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ecb

Let's say I have a ciphertext encrypted with CTR.

And I know the nonce used to be encrypted as well as the AES key. Is it possible to decrypt the given ciphertext using ECB mode?

*sorry if this is already asked, i looked around couldn't find anything*

Comment: All modes of a block cipher are constructed from its most primitive operation, the block cipher permutation, also known as ECB mode. So yes, you can decrypt with the information you have.

Comment: Yes, you can create CTR mode yourself basically. It's not hard at all, if you know anything about handling bytes. Note that this isn't yet a programming question, so it's off topic on [SO]. There is [crypto.se] but please try and at least [read the Wikipedia page on these kind of modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) before asking.